# Magento footer links not removed in custom theme

Tags: theme, luma-theme, magento2.2.4

I create a custom theme based on Luma, with the path like:

```
/app/design/frontend/Theme1/custom/
```

Now I want to remove the footer links and edit the following file:

```
/app/design/frontend/Theme1/custom/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Inside the file I added `<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>` after `<body>`

The strange thing is that it's not working. When I change the default Luma theme from the /vendor folder, it works well.

My custom Theme1 is enabled from Content -> Design in the backend.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try flushing cache as there looks like an extra caching for footer?

Comment: @Nidheesh Thanks for your reply. Yes we flushed the entire cache. When editing the default Luma theme file inside the /vendor folder, it works well.